# How to store a random SQL query by its ID?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables

```
$randWord = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM words ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

After I call a random row from my table (which includes a word, its definition, and an id column) I want to store that word and definition so I can edit it if another button is pressed. From what I've seen online the common solution is to store it by its id. How do I store a random SQL query by its id?

Comment: You should look into mysqli or PDO for future.  Fetch the row into an array and store it by the `$row['primary_key']`?

Comment: Store the ID in [`$_SESSION`](http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php), then later you can retrieve the row with `WHERE id = :id`. Also, `ORDER() BY RAND()` is pretty much the worst possible thing you can do in a query. Stop it.

Comment: how would I store it by `$row['primary_key']`? i do have an id column, im just unsure of the code to store it for later access.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of where the pro tip

> Never use `SELECT *` in software, instead give the names of the
>   columns you want.

would have helped you.  If your `words` table has an `id` column, store that value.

Comment: how do i store it to use later? just `$currentid = $db_field['id']` and then use $currentid later on?

Comment: Yes, if your table has a unique (maybe primary key auto-incrementing) id column, and you need to retrieve an arbitrary row later, you can store that row's id.

Answer (score 1):

RAND() and fetching by * is strongly not recommended because of it's bad performance.

Suggested example:

```
$total = mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM words'), 0);
$randWord = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('SELECT wid, word, definition FROM words LIMIT '.rand(0, $total - 1).', 1'), 0);
```

Where mysql_result obtains the total number of records, mysql_fetch_array turns the result into an array. rand(0, $total - 1) generates a random number between available records, and then satisfy the [LIMIT start, limit] statement in the query.

You may build up your own DB class to reduce the code redundancy.

For your question, you should create a field as a primary key (or unique identifier). Like the 'wid' field I suggested above. Then you can output it as the value of a button and so on.